# Problem calculating the sum of arithmetic progression when using prompt()

Tags: javascript

I am trying this code to add a number starting from 1 to n using this mathematical equation:`n = n(n+1) /2`

```js
var n = prompt("enter a number");

function adding(n) {
  let N = n * (n + 1) / 2;
  return N;
}
alert(adding(n));
```

but it's not working in prompt. It works like this:

```js
function adding(n) {
  let N = n * (n + 1) / 2;
  return N;
}
console.log("answer", adding(100));
```

Comment: `prompt` returns a string. You need to convert it to a number. `var n = Number(prompt("enter a number"))` Otherwise `n + 1`concatenates 1 to the string instead of adding 1.  For `n = 2`,  `n + 1` becomes 21 not 3